# Using Drupal as client of a web service

Tags: 7, services

I need to use Drupal as client for a web service, for extracting data and showing it in a view or as content. (The format use is JSON or REST.)

I use a [Web Service Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient) module in Drupal 7, and the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module in Drupal 6, but I don't know how to use them. I read the documentation but I don't get any result.

Can anyone help on this issue, or tell me how to use these modules? Is there any other module for this purpose?

---

A possible solution: I find a module called [XML VIEWS](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_xml) but this module convert only XML files.

Now, I programing in this module for convert the JSON to XML.

In this files: `xml_views_plugin_query_xml.inc`

In this function: *Execute*

Anyone have another solution?

Comment: There were some good presentations on this at austin (11)drupalcamp: http://vimeo.com/33785095 http://vimeo.com/33091201

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Drupal has specific functions that can help with communicating with a web service, and handling JSON input.
Drupal 7 has the following functions:

- [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) is the function to make a HTTP request to a remote site, and it handles GET, POST, PUT or any other HTTP requests; it also handles redirects.
- [drupal_http_build_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_http_build_query/7) transform an array in an `rawurlencode()`-d string.
- [drupal_json_decode()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_decode/7) decodes a JSON string in PHP code.
- [drupal_json_encode()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7) encode a PHP variable into a string that is handled by JSON.

With those functions you can write your own custom module to make requests to a site implementing a web service.

If there are some restrictions about the number of requests that can be done to the web server, you can use the Drupal functions to cache the result obtained from the web server:

- [cache_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_get/7), to get the data saved in the cache
- [cache_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/7), to save the data in the cache

To notice that Drupal supports more than one cache bin, and modules can use their own cache bins, when necessary.
Drupal supports also cache items that are automatically removed at the successive cache swipe (see the description for the [CACHE_TEMPORARY](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/CACHE_TEMPORARY/7) constant). Implementing [hook_flush_caches()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_flush_caches/7), the modules allow to the administrator users to clean the cache used by the module when the "Clear" button on the "Performance" page is clicked, or any times a module calls [drupal_flush_all_caches()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/7).

In Drupal 7, cache data for frequently used data are associated with a static variable handled with [drupal_static()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7). When the data is really frequently used when outputting the same page, code similar to the following one is used:

```
  // Use the advanced drupal_static() pattern, since this is called very often.
  static $drupal_static_fast;
  if (!isset($drupal_static_fast)) {
    $drupal_static_fast['implementations'] = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
  }
  $implementations = &$drupal_static_fast['implementations'];

  // …

  // Fetch implementations from cache.
  if (empty($implementations)) {
    $implementations = cache_get('module_implements', 'cache_bootstrap');
    if ($implementations === FALSE) {
      $implementations = array();
    }
    else {
      $implementations = $implementations->data;
    }
  }
```

The code is part of [module_implements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_implements/7).

Comment: Did you try https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient? I'm interested if this module helps with ws client implementation

Answer (score 2):

Every time I have needed to consume a webservice, I have just created a PHP class based around [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) or [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) in conjunction with [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) or [simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_string).

The class then gets accessed in a module via a getter function that uses [drupal_static](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7), or the `$static` pattern for Drupal 6.

I then use this inside my custom blocks, menu callbacks, etc, as needed.

EDIT

@kiamlaluno's answer is correct and demonstrates a way to do this all through the Drupal API.  The primary reason I don't do this is that I prefer to abstract the webservice class in a way that allows me to use it in other applications.  There are advantages and disadvantages to this, so weigh your options.

Comment: Does that mean that I schedule to consume data from the webservice? Is there a solution as sitebuilder with modules?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: In other words, i search a solution that doesn't involve a programing. A solution like a site builder with modules. But, if in my case involve programing i need the steps for do it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of abstract webservice class?